Zloty cash to Malaysian Ringgit
I have 5,000 zloty in cash. Can we convert it to Malaysian ringgit at any bank? I have asked the money exchanger, they don't buy and sell zloty. Thank you.

Converting directly between two currencies which are not commonly traded outside their own countries can be difficult and, even if possible, you will probably get a poor rate.
Buying ringgit in Poland will be difficult and the rate will be poor.
Similarly, selling zloty in Malaysia will be difficult and the rate will be poor.
If you need to use cash then it is easiest to use an intermediate currency which is commonly traded internationally such as the dollar or euro.  Buy euros or dollars in Poland and sell them in Malaysia.  You will pay commission (effective if not explicit) twice but this will probably apply even if you find a direct conversion; they will probably notionally convert it to and from an intermediate currency.
The easiest solution is to not use cash, use a card.  In a recent trip to Poland, I never touched any zloty.  However, I was in Warsaw; in smaller towns, cash would be useful or necessary but drawing cash from an ATM would probably be best.  You will need to check with your bank but there is a good chance that it will be better than changing cash in a bureau de change.  I have not been to Malaysia for a long time but I would expect that it is similar: cards easy in big cities and an ATM for cash to use in smaller places.
If you are already in Malaysia with zloty and don't expect to return to Poland soon or ever then it will be hard.  5000 is a significant sum so it is worth trying.  Finding a Polish tourist might be your best chance.  However, they are probably more likely to want to sell rather than buy zloty.  You might be able to do a deal at a pretty bad rate.

You don't have to get very far off the beaten path in Poland before you need cash. I only spent a couple of days in Poland last year and did at least three times need cash for payments where cards were not accepted: accomodation, parking and bus ticket.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo A good point but you could draw some cash on your card.  I'll add that.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo: "get very far off the beaten path" out of curiosity, where was that?

@WoJ In the area around Terespol.
